# jquery: 3 level vertical menu

Tags: jquery, menu, accordion

I've been looking around for a couple of hours for a 3 level vertical accordion menu. Something like this: http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/javascript-accordion/index.html

Something really simple is enough, but i cant get anything to work with 3 levels. Can anyone provide me with a jquery snippet to get me started? I've tried using

```
 $('li').click(function(){

           $(this).children('ul').children('li').toggle();

        });
```

but it hides the submenu as well, not just the current childrens. Thanks

Comment: any problem with plugin ? why u dont use ?

Comment: I want something more simple. No design or animations required

Comment: check the ui.accordion, it is simple, u just need to create the html, and the plugin will do the rest :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

example from scratch:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        level 2
        <ul>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>b</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        level 2
        <ul>
            <li>
                level 3
                <ul>
                    <li>c</li>
                    <li>d</li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>e</li>
            <li>f</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

$('li').click(function(ev) {
    $(this).find('>ul').slideToggle();
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aCaEG/

Comment: Perfect, just what i needed. Didnt know about the stopPropagation :) Thanks

Comment: +1 for what's probably the simplest accordion-menu script ever.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aCaEG/2/ will also close siblings (and their descendants) automatically.

Comment: @mblase75 or Andy; http://jsfiddle.net/8deWJ/ Do you know how to modify the text or add a class for all the listitems that have children. I have made a loop in the jsfiddle, but the text for a li with children obviously includes the text for its children as well.  I just want ot show a "+" or something similiar to the elements who have children. Something like this, but with the text edited instead of the css: http://jsfiddle.net/8deWJ/3/

Comment: @Andy is there an easy way to make the + turn in to - when theyre expanded?

Answer (score 0):

check [**ui.accordion**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) and see if helps you.

in my opinion, dont try to do something that already exist.

Comment: in my opinion, try everything even if it exists to learn how to do it.

Comment: yeah, sure, but why reinvent the wheel if u have a safety source that works perfect ?

Comment: He learned what stopPropagation was, didn't he? Learn learn learn!

Comment: for some trivial problems (like that) i find it unnecessary to include and set up jquery ui for example. also many scripts or plugins don't work exactly the way you want and you'll spend more time tweaking them than you'd to write the functionality yourself. But yea, i don't say you shouldn't use any scripts or plugins at all. I only say you'll learn a lot if you don't just use them, but actually read through them and try to understand how they did it :)

Comment: @Andy yeah, of course, if we have time to learn how to do it you are precisely right, but i think when we dont have't , we go to a safety source and put to runn :)