# avoid empty list items in accordion menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm experimenting with an accordion menu following the jQuery example in the accepted answer to this question: [jquery: 3 level vertical menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653457/jquery-3-level-vertical-menu):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('li').click(function(ev) {
$(this).find('>ul').slideToggle()
    .end().siblings().find('ul').slideUp();
ev.stopPropagation();
});
});
```

My problem is that when I add css to make it look a bit like a jQm listview it gets empty list items just below Level 2 and Level 3. If I remove:

```
display: block;
```

from the css the menu looks like a list and has no empty list items. Is there a way around it where I get to keep the block appearance?

Please check my fiddle for complete code:
http://jsfiddle.net/karin_A/aCaEG/564/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just missing a couple of closing  tags is all.

```
<li><a href="#"> Level 2



<li><a href="#"> Level 3
```

Comment: Oh, that's really embarrassing. Thanks!

Comment: No, it's good when it's something simple. Makes it easier to fix!